# href="tel" opening Add to Contact Popup in Cordova App

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, visual-studio-cordova

I am using simple code to open the dial screen of mobile.

```
 document.location.href = "tel:+1-1800-555-5555";
```

But when I am running app on Nexus Tablet, Its opening a pop Up with Add to Contact or Close option.

I want to open the number in dialer screen.

Whats an issue??

Answer (score 3):

Maybe because it's a tablet, so there is no dialer?

Comment: Ya I think you are right...Sorry for silly question :)